# Python3: How to annotate the type of a factory method to match subclass type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

If I have a base class with a factory method like

```
class A:
  def gen_new_instance(self) -> 'A':
    return copy.deepcopy(self)
```

and a subclass

```
class B(A):
  def gen_new_instance(self) -> 'B':
    inst = super().gen_new_instance()
    # ... set some additional things on `inst`
    return inst  # inferred type is A, but should really be B
```

how can I annotate the super class `A` to indicate that it will do the right thing and return an instance of the subclass rather than an instance of `A`?